# ASP.NET MVC 5 - Part of application running independently of client

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-mvc-5

I am considering how I can improve the performance of my website, which is made with ASP.NET MVC 5. I want the server to receive data from the database every second and save the data in RAM memory. The idea is that the client will receive the data that exists in the server's RAM memory and not query the database every time, as this would be too heavy for the database in the long run.

This means that I need the back-end of the ASP.NET application to run independently of whether a client is using it or not.

Is this possible? And if so, how do I go about it practically? Where do I implemented this part of the program that queries the database and saves the data in RAM?

Comment: The concept you need to research is called "caching"

Comment: It can be achieved using a Redis cache: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/redis-cache/cache-web-app-howto. It is an Azure solution, I am unsure if or how you can use it if you are not on Azure.

Comment: Caching with SQL Notifications to refresh the cache will be somewhat like what you describe: https://www.apriorit.com/dev-blog/386-caching-in-dot-net